# Meteor helper doesn't set data

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, meteor-blaze

I need to get images array in template onRendered hook, and then get these images in helper for slider creation. This slider should be created when modal is open. But when i run this code, helper doesn't send any data to template. In console.log(i can see this array).
I have this code:

```
Template.slider.onRendered(function() {

    this.autorun(()=> {
        let mainImg = this.data.mainImage || null;
        let imgs = this.data.images || [];

        this.data.imgSet = Images
            .find({_id: { $in: [mainImg, ...imgs] }})
            .map(img => img.url());
    });
});
```

and helper:

```
Template.slider.helpers({
    images() {
        let imgSet = this.imgSet;

        if(imgSet) {
            const slider = $('#vertical').lightSlider({
                gallery: true

            });

            return this.imgSet;
        }

        return [];
    }
});
```

my template file:

```
<ul id="vertical" class="light_slider">
   {{#each images}}
          <li data-thumb="{{this}}">
               <img src="{{this}}" style="height:100%"/>
         </li>
   {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your helper doesn't depend on any reactive variable, that's why it works only once, regardless of your `imgSet` variable update.

To get what you want you have to make reactive variable and update it.

Something like this:

```
Template.slider.onRendered(function() {

    this.imgSet = new ReactiveVar([]);

    this.autorun(()=> {
        const mainImg = this.data.mainImage || null;
        const imgs = this.data.images || [];

        const imgSet = Images
            .find({_id: { $in: [mainImg, ...imgs] }})
            .map(img => img.url());

        this.imgSet.set(imgSet);
    });
});

Template.slider.helpers({
    images() {
        const imgSet = Template.instance().imgSet.get();

        if(imgSet) {
            // let's give render the time to rerender
            // though I'd recommend to put that into onRendered
            Meteor.setTimeout(() => {
                $('#vertical').lightSlider({
                    gallery: true
                });
            }, 50);

            return imgSet;
        }

        return [];
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. What do you mean "I'd recommend to put that into onRendered"

Comment: I have added my template

Comment: Ok, could you try my code, but without re-initializing `lightSlider`? So you will be able to see whether html is re-rendered or not.